# SVG path animation flicker on Safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari

On Safari the middle path of this SVG burger menu flickers on the dasharray animation. I cannot find the cause of this issue. Has anyone encountered this before?

Pen here:

http://codepen.io/DaveArm1864/pen/pEvKxY?editors=0100

CSS here:

```
@import "nib"

easeInOutSine = cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.050, 0.550, 0.950)
easeOutBack   = cubic-bezier(0.250,-0.250, 0.750, 1.250)
easing = easeOutBack
duration = .5s

body
html
div
  background #292A38
  margin 0
  padding 0
  width 100%
  height 100%
  text-align center

dash-offset-cross = 0px
cross-length = 950px

svg
  width 200px
  height 150px
  cursor pointer
  transform translate3d(0,0,0)

path
  fill none
  transition stroke-dashoffset duration easing, stroke-dasharray duration easing
  stroke-width 40px
  stroke-linecap round
  stroke #A06BA5
  stroke-dashoffset 0px
  &#top
  &#bottom
    stroke-dasharray 240px cross-length
  &#middle
    stroke-dasharray 240px 240px

.cross
  path
    &#top
    &#bottom
      stroke-dashoffset -650px
      stroke-dashoffset -650px
    &#middle
      stroke-dashoffset -115px
      stroke-dasharray 1px 220px
```